# Stop NAudio in other window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, naudio

My application has three windows. In first window NAudio starts to play music file.
When clicked on "Next" button, this window is closed and a new one is opened. Music is still playing. After click on "Next2" button the next window is opened and I need to stop music there, but `waveOutDevice.Stop();` doesn't work, because it isn't declared in this window.

Main window:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private static IWavePlayer waveOutDevice;
    private static AudioFileReader audioFileReader;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string directory1 = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath;
        waveOutDevice = new WaveOut();
        audioFileReader = new AudioFileReader(directory1+@"\sample\main.mp3");
        waveOutDevice.Init(audioFileReader);
        waveOutDevice.Play();
    }

    private void Next1b_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Next1 win3 = new Next1();
        win3.Show();
        this.Close();

    }
```

}

and the last one window:

```
public partial class Next2 : Window
{
    public Next2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void stopmusic_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //waveOutDevice.Stop();
    }
}
```

Is there any way how to stop playing this music file, or at least how to stop all music files that are playing?

Comment: Events, static methods or properties, passing objects to constructors of new forms/windows, etc. There are many ways of doing what you need. I suggest researching some so you can learn, picking one, giving it a try and then post that code here if you need help. Right now I feel you need to learn more than just get the answer.

Comment: As bland mentioned, there's many ways to do this. You could pass a reference as a parameter, but considering what you basically want is a music player that persists throughout multiple forms, you could declare the `IWavePlayer waveOutDevice` within your `Program.cs` (or maybe a separate static class), where all 3 forms can easily access it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a public static method to cancel playback.   For instance:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static void StopPlayback()
    {
        if (waveOutDevice != null && waveOutDevice.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
            waveOutDevice.Stop();
    }
}
```

Now call that with `MainWindow.StopPlayback()` from anywhere in your code.